# Errors while compiling asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, compilation

Hey guys,
i have a website, i want to place the compile code on the production server, now i took the code on the local machine and trying to compile source code on local machine, but whenever i compile the code, in one of my control(ascx.cs) file i am getting error that the control does not exists in current context, i checked everything, Inherits, CodeFile, even in the code behind(.cs) file, everything is perfect, even i get the control id in the intellisense, when i remove the control and again add the same using intellisense, the errors gets removed but after i publish site, the same error comes again....

Please reply with some suggestion/solutions.

Comment: show us some code, error messages, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue before when referencing another project. It would give it intellisense, but then trying to compile would cause errors and take away intellisense. Removing and re-adding it would give me intellisense back.

The problem ended up being the target framework. The project was referencing .NET 4 Client Profile, whereas the project it was referencing was just .NET 4. Apparently this difference is subtle enough to trip up visual studio in the confusing way described above.

So take a look at your project's target framework, maybe you'll get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check your `Inherits`  or `CodeFile`.  I've had this happen before where I had them pointing at the wrong files.